# Select a percentage of rows for each group and calculate a stastistics for a specific column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset:

```
value <- c(3,4,5,4,3,4,5,4,3,4,3,4,6,5,4,5,6,7,5,4,6,4,6,3,2,6,7,4,7,8,5,6,7,5,5,7,8,7,45,3,4,3,4,6,4,3,2,1,2,3,4)
Sub <- c(rep("sub1", 10), rep("sub2",25), rep("sub3", 16))

dat <-as.data.frame(cbind(Sub, value))
```

It'a only an example, but it is useful to give you an idea of my purposes.

What I need to do is:

1. To take the fist 10, 20,30, 40,50,60 70,80,90,100% of values of each Sub e calculate a statistics, such as the mean, or the maximum value and so on.
2. To create a dataframe like this:

   ```
          p10    p20    p30    p40    p50    p60    p70    p80    p90    p100
   ```

   Sub1
   Sub2

   Sub...

I used I function like this to calculate a percentage of rows to analyze.

```
subset_percent <- function(x, start=0, end=100) {
  stopifnot(
    is.numeric(start), is.numeric(end),
    start < end, start >= 0, end <= 100
  )
  nr <- nrow(x)
  rows <- 1:nr
  srt <- ceiling(start*nr/100)
  end <-floor(end*nr/100)
  x[srt:end,]
}
```

My intent was to use dplyr to apply this function to each group:

```
newdat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(Sub) %>% 
  summarise(
p10 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,10)$value),
p20 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,20)$value),
p30 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,30)$value),
p40 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,40)$value),
p50 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,50)$value),
p60 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,60)$value),
p70 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,70)$value),
p80 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,80)$value),
p90 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,90)$value),
p100 = mean(subset_percent(dat,0,100)$value))
```

However the output was not correct, because I got this erroneous result:

```
Sub     p10   p20   p30   p40   p50   p60   p70   p80   p90  p100
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 sub1    3.8   3.9  4.07   4.4  4.36   4.7  4.83  5.98  5.78  5.39
2 sub2    3.8   3.9  4.07   4.4  4.36   4.7  4.83  5.98  5.78  5.39
3 sub3    3.8   3.9  4.07   4.4  4.36   4.7  4.83  5.98  5.78  5.39
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `cut` to divide the data and use `quantile` as `breaks` within each `Sub. Calculate` mean` within each group and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Sub) %>%
  mutate(group = cut(value, c(-Inf, unique(quantile(value, seq(0, 1, 0.1)))), 
                     labels = FALSE) * 10) %>%
  group_by(group, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value, names_prefix = 'p')
```

Tip - Don't do `dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(...))` instead do `dat <- data.frame(...)` i.e

```
dat <- data.frame(Sub, value)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak... unfortunately I got some strange result, using your method